# How can I check whether cck field's content is changed in node_update hook?

Tags: nodes, updating

I want to check whether cck field's content is changed in node_update

I tried the same with following conditions but it gave me incorrect result.

```
if($node->field_event_type['und'][0]['value'] == $node->original->field_event_type['und'][0]['value']){
   echo "same";
}else{
   echo "changed"
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7):

> Note that when this hook is invoked, the changes have not yet been written to the database

So you can use

```
$old_node = node_load($node->nid);
```

Then simply compare `$node` provided to a hook with `$old_node` obtained from database.

Comment: I think that only works if you module has priority over CCK. For example, a module named `alexis` would appear before `cck`. Otherwise, you have to change your weight. In all other situations, the data will already have been updated in the database...

Comment: Of course, I'm on Drupal 6, and they may also have changed the order in which things happen...

Comment: Actually I found a way in Drupal 6, in case others use that version, which is to load the "old" node in the "presave" node API. Then do their compare in the "update" callback.